# how to pull new changes to google app engine using command shell

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-shell

I have a node React project in Bitbucket which is already deployed in Google App Engine. I have made some changes to the my application and I would like to know how to deploy the new changes to the Google App Engine using command shell.

I have tried `git pull` command it says that there is no repository, even if I can see the project files.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Support here!

With the amount of details given and seeing what you are trying to do, I think that the best solution for you would be using [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/).

If you end up using Cloud Source Repositories, [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository) you'll find a guide explaining how to mirror a Bitbucket repository. After mirroring the desired repository, as you are using Google App Engine, you should read [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-app-engine) in which it is described how to integrate Cloud Source Repositories with Google App Engine.

Please bear in mind that using Cloud Source Repositories might involve additional charges if you exceed the free tier, this is explained in the [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/pricing) section for Cloud Source Repositories.

If you don't want to use Cloud Source Repositories, [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html) you'll find how to clone a Bitbucket repository.